# while loop in masm32 loops infinitely

Tags: assembly, while-loop, masm32

I am new to assembly language. so started writing small programs. I have written a basic loop program to print "*" pyramid. but the program goes into infinite loop. I am pasting the code below. can someone please help?
 start:

```
   mov ecx,2
   invoke StdOut, addr startProg

label_1:

   .while ecx > 0

   push ecx
       pop aInt

     .while aInt > 0
       invoke StdOut, addr star
       sub aInt, 1
     .endw

        dec ecx
    .endw

     ;invoke StdOut, addr newline


   jmp out_
out_:
   invoke ExitProcess, 0
```

end start

Comment: Your going to need a bit more than that for a pyramid.  Here - http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/302352-nasmwindows-lets-create-a-pyramid-of-characters/ I describe in steps how to create a pyramid.

Answer (score 3):

Invoke calls the method via the __stdcall calling convention. Part of that convention is that EAX, ECX and EDX are not preserved over that call. This is why your ECX and EAX registers are not decrementing and causing the loop to stop.

Comment: you mean If I use local variables instead of these registers. shall that work?

Comment: I was SO frustrated with these infinite loop i was getting all the time, i was about pull ever hair in my head out! And the answer was this simple... Iv made some nice p&p functions now THANKS +1

Answer (score 1):

Like @SecurityMatt stated, the reason you get trapped in a infinite loop is because the value of `ecx` is modified in your call to `StdOut`.
You can avoid this by preserving your registers using `push` and then restoring them using `pop`:

```
.while ecx > 0
   push ecx
   pop aInt
   ; preserve state of `ecx`
   push ecx
   .while aInt > 0
     invoke StdOut, addr star
     sub aInt, 1
   .endw
   ; restore ecx
   pop ecx
   dec ecx
.endw
```

You could also use `pushad` and `popad` in order to push/pop all general-purpose register values on and off the stack.

```
; push general-purpose registers values onto stack
pushad
invoke StdOut, addr star
; restore general-purpose registers
popad
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably confusing assembly instructions with macros.
The .while is not an assembly instruction, it is a macro.
Same for all directives that begin with '.'

Comment: If only assembly was that easy :(